# Angular Component & injectable template

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-components

The team I am on has recently upgraded from angular 1.2 to 1.3 and we're adding [Todd Moto's component polyfill](https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-component) to aid our eventual migration to angular 2. While going over the docs for component() in 1.x I saw that they have a feature for injectable templates, but I am unable to find an equivalent for this in the 2.x docs.

For some parts of our product template injection seems tempting to use, but should this be avoided in 1.x since there is no equivalent in 2.x (I'm assuming for security reasons) or does Angular2 have another recommend approach/alternative to this?